# How to add multiple column Unique key in mySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-constraint, unique-key

I want to add the unique constarint I am using the following query but it gives me an error of SQL syntax

ALTER TABLE user_device ADD CONSTRAINT `UKnfrn6f2pu3tqcwhqen0d6cq7u` (`owner`,`push_notification_id`);

where is the mistake :| 
it highlighted the mistake in push_notification_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE user_device ADD CONSTRAINT UKnfrn6f2pu3tqcwhqen0d6cq7u UNIQUE KEY  (owner,push_notification_id);
```

Try above code.
You didn't mention which type of key you want to make on that combination of column.
So i had mention that using **`UNIQUE KEY`** keyword.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this.

```
ALTER TABLE user_device ADD unique index UKnfrn6f2pu3tqcwhqen0d6cq7u (owner,push_notification_id);
```